# Extendible equals sign

Tags: symbols, amsmath, macros

I have a command that has been floating around in my standard preamble for a while:

```
\newcommand{\xeq}[1]{\stackrel{\;#1}{\cleaders\hbox{=\!}\hfill}\:}
```

It is meant to mimic the AMS-LaTeX extendible arrow symbols `\xleftarrow` and `\xrightarrow`.

It's not perfect for two reasons:

1. It does not take the optional lower argument like the AMS `\xrightarrow[down]{up}`
2. The overlap of the constituent equals signs is slightly visible.

Does anyone have a better command or know of a package with such a command?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you can more or less copy the definitions from `amsmath.sty`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\Relbarfill@}{\arrowfill@\Relbar\Relbar\Relbar}
\newcommand*{\xeq}[2][]{\ext@arrow 0055\Relbarfill@{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a \xeq[uuuuu]{vvv} b$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15):

The [`extarrows`](http://ctan.org/pkg/extarrows) package provides `\xlongequal[below]{above}`.