# Text over/under implies arrow?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath

I'm currently trying to write over/under an implies arrow in LaTeX (in math mode):

```
\implies_{text}
```

This places the text lower, but next to the arrow, not below it. How can I get it below the arrow?

Comment: Related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4813/extendible-equals-sign if you're willing to load `amsmath` then I strongly expect that the answer to your question will be very similar to the accepted answer to that question.

Comment: Already running amsmath, sorry.

Comment: That you are already running amsmath is a _good_ thing, not a bad one!

Comment: the "sorry" wasn't for running amsmath, but not providing the detail in the question ;)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use `\xRightarrow[below]{above}` from the `mathtools` (or `extpfeil`) package or `\xLongrightarrow[below]{above}` from `extarrows`. (Have a look at [“How to look up a math symbol?”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.)

If you want to keep the the same arrow length as implies, you can use `\underset` and `\overset` from `amsmath`, e.g. `\underset{below}{\implies}`, or maybe `\underset{\mathclap{below}}{\implies}` (`\mathclap` makes it so that “below” doesn’t introduce extra vertical space if it is longer than the arrow. It is included in the immensely useful `mathtools` package).

Comment: Sadly, the proposed arrow looks different than the implies arrow, so it wouldn't fit with the rest of the equations :/ thanks for your help though.

Comment: @femaref Except for the length they look exactly the same on my system. Do you want the length to stay constant?

Comment: the second thing helped me. For you, comparision of the two arrows: http://www.abload.de/img/arrows_zoomednbxj.png and http://www.abload.de/img/arrowsrbfs.png

Comment: @femaref except for the length and bad rendering (which should go away when printed -- there is only supposed to be one black line without that gray fuzziness) they look the same to me.

Comment: `\underset` FTW.  And I need to learn more about `mathtools`.

Comment: @Femaref: You are using 12pt, aren't you? You might want to have a look at  [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4684/1235) if you want the arrows look better.