# AMSMath \implies and a superscript symbol

Tags: amsmath

I would like to have a superscript symbol attached to the implies-arrow, i.e., something like that

```
\[ \implies^f \]
```

However, this does not work. A similar question was asked here: [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5154/text-over-under-implies-arrow)

But just for a text above the arrow. So this does not solve my problem. Does someone has an idea how to solve this? I would like to have the same arrow length as the AMSMath implies arrow has.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of `\implies` is

```
% amsmath.sty, line 308:
\newcommand{\implies}{\DOTSB\;\Longrightarrow\;}
```

which means that you're setting the superscript after the thick space.

My suggestion is to define a new command

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\simplies}{\DOTSB\Longrightarrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
& a \simplies^f b \\
& a \implies b \\
& a \implies^f b
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The spacing around `\implies` is too big anyway. The second and third line are just for comparison.

[image]

If you want to preserve the spacing of `\implies`, you have no choice other than defining `\simplies` with an argument; probably optional, so you can use `\simplies` as a drop-in replacement for `\implies`:

```
\newcommand{\simplies}[1][]{\DOTSB\;\implies^{#1}\;}
```

and the above formula should be typed as

```
a \simplies[f] b
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation! I solved it by defining a new command as you said above.