# Extendible \cong congruence sign

Tags: symbols, amsmath

This question is very similar to [Extendible equals sign](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4813/extendible-equals-sign) but the solutions given there do not apply immediately.

At times I woud like to clarify the nature of a mathematical congruence. So I have defined in my preamble

```
\newcommand*\morph[1]{\underset{\mbox{\tiny #1}}{\cong}}
```

So I can write things like `\morph{diff}` and `\morph{hom}` to differentiate between different congruences. But even with the `\mbox` content set to `\tiny`, the text is still wider than the congruence sign. Any ideas?

Comment: Reducing the font size, although possible, would make the label almost illegible; on the other side, making an extended version of `\cong` will produce (IMO) inconsistent results. In this particular case (again, in my opinion) I'd rather stick to the behaviour exhibited by your current definition. Another option would be to select different symbols.

Comment: Sometimes, when I have this sort of issue with features not in LaTeX that I think I want, I realize after trying to produce them that they are absent because they are a bad idea.  It looks to me like you want to label "congruences" which are isomorphisms, in which case perhaps you could use `\xrightarrow[under]{over}` and put a `\sim` in one position?  You could also use `\widetilde` to some (probably limited) extent to place a tilde over an extendible equals sign, though I haven't tried it so I'll leave the suggestion here as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could always use `\resizebox` to stretch the symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\morph[1]{%
    \setbox0=\hbox{\scriptsize#1}%
    \setbox2=\hbox{$\m@th{\cong}$}%
    \stackrel{\copy0}{%
        \ifdim\wd2<\wd0
            \resizebox{\wd0}{\ht2}{$\m@th{\cong}$}%
        \else
            \cong
        \fi
    }%
}
\begin{document}
\[X\morph{long text}Y\morph{i}Z\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hum, something's weird. It works if I invoke using `latex test; dvipdf test; xpdf test.pdf`. But it doesn't work if I invoke using `pdflatex test; xpdf test.pdf`. Any ideas?

Comment: Let me clarify: doesn't work means "where the symbol should display, there is nothing there." `\resizebox` works by itself with `pdflatex`: if I have something inline like `\resizebox{3cm}{2cm}{test}` or the same with something in mathmode inside the third argument, it gets displayed and scaled. But somehow not the command you gave above.

Comment: Hum, `\scalebox` however doesn't have the same problems. Looking at my use case, I am happy to now just scale the width of the symbol by 33%.

Comment: @Willie: I can't imagine why the code doesn't work for you with pdflatex. It is what I used.

Comment: @Willie: If `\scalebox` works, then so should `\resizebox`. They both end up using the same macro `\Gscale@box`.

Comment: Maybe bug in old version of `pdflatex`? The TeX distribution installed on the office computers here is a bit outdated. I'll try again at home to see if that is the case.

Comment: Actually, now I realized that hardcoding the `\resize` size in also works. So if anything the problem would be in the parsing of `\wd0` and `\ht2`.

Comment: Oh boy, it just occurred to me (once again) that on this system the backend is `pdfetex`, not `pdfTeX`...

Comment: Confirmed that it works on a `pdfTeX` system. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Of course, whilst agreeing that this Not Recommended, it's also fairly similar to something I do: I like to make arrows and so forth a little more conspicuous in presentation by making them a bit bigger.  So my method for doing that adapts reasonably well to this situation.

That method is to use ... TikZ!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\newcommand{\xcong}[1]{%
\mathrel{\tikz[baseline=0pt] {
   \node[above] at (0,1.2ex) (a) {\(\scriptstyle #1\)};
   \draw[preaction={
      transform canvas={yshift=-.5ex},
      draw,
      decorate,
      decoration={lineto}},
     preaction={
      transform canvas={yshift=-1ex},
      draw,
      decorate,
      decoration={lineto}}]
    (a.south west) .. controls +(.25,.15) and +(-.25,-.15) .. (a.south east);
 }}}

\begin{document}
\(
A \cong B \quad A \xcong{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h} B
\)
\end{document}
```

Okay, it's not going to win any design awards ...

[image: extensible congruence sign]

Comment: To save on preaction, you could use `double, double equal sign distance` (as I just found out for a similar problem).

Comment: Have you heard of the `calligraphy` library? (Just kidding.;-) I think this will allow one to produce an even nicer version thereof, which could also be used in packages like `tikz-cd`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I'd have to check the dates, but my guess would be that this predates that library by a good year or so.  Nice idea, though.

Comment: I think so, too. But it would make a great extensible wide tilde, I'd think.

Comment: Feel free to have a go!  You'd get a guaranteed up-vote from me.