# Stretch \sim in matrix transformations

Tags: overset, substack

I'm sure there is already such a question, but after searching I didn't find anything.

I'm looking for the method that would make `\sim` stretch depending on the text above.

Here is the example of what I need.

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63545/1090

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to produce a longer `\sim` with a small letter on top](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19384/5764)

Comment: I need to write above the `\sim`, not under it.

Comment: above/below is a minor detail, the hard part is getting the oversized sim then it's just a matter of stacking them with `\stackrel` or similar in which case  you can stack above or below or both

Comment: @DavidCarlisle so could you add an answer with the method you offer? I can't really get how to put something above so that it would stretch `\widetilde `

Comment: @Werner it seems that I need manually set the strech factor. So I will rather wait for the answer.

Comment: Is there a particular meaning of operations being above or below the stretched ~? Students *will* attribute some.

Answer (score 3):

The Plain TeX based solution without TikZ:

```
\newbox\wtilde
\setbox\wtilde=\hbox{%
   \pdfliteral{q 2 0 0 2 0 0 cm}\lower1.5ex\rlap{$\widetilde{\hphantom{xxx}}$}\pdfliteral{Q}%
    \hphantom{xxxxxx}}

$$
  \pmatrix{1&1&1&1\cr1&1&1&1\cr1&1&1&1\cr1&1&1&1}
  \vcenter{\baselineskip=.7\baselineskip\halign{\hfil$\scriptstyle#$\hfil\cr
     r_2 - r_1 \cr
     r_3 - 2r_1 \cr
     \copy\wtilde \cr
     r_4 - 2r_2 \cr
     \null \cr 
  }}
  \pmatrix{1&1&1&1\cr1&1&1&1\cr1&1&1&1\cr1&1&1&1}
$$

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Running with `pdftex` gives me `! Undefined control sequence.` error.

Comment: @Stephen corrected.

Comment: Thanks. The result is pretty nice (I attached an output screenshot in your answer). And where can I find the documentation for `\pdfliteral`?

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun: an attempt based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15855/194703) and the `calligraphy` library by the same author.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,calligraphy,decorations.pathreplacing}
% based on: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15855/194703
\newcommand{\xwidesim}[2][]{%
\setbox0\hbox{$\scriptstyle#2$}%
\setbox1\hbox{$\scriptstyle#1$}%
\mathrel{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0pt] 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\wmax}{max(max(\wd0,\wd1)+4,12)}
\node[above] at (0,{0.2*\wmax*1pt}) (a) {\(\scriptstyle #2\)};
\node[below] at (0,0) (b) {\(\scriptstyle #1\)};
\pen (-135:{min(\wmax,10)*0.1pt}) -- (45:{min(\wmax,10)*0.1pt});
\path (-\wmax*0.5pt-2pt,{0.025*\wmax*1pt+2pt}) coordinate(first)
(\wmax*0.5pt+2pt,{0.025*\wmax*1pt+2pt}) coordinate(last);
\calligraphy[light,line width=1.5pt]
(first) .. controls
 ($($(first)!0.25!(last)$)!{0.1*\wmax+0.4pt}!90:(last)$) 
 .. ($(first)!0.5!(last)$) 
 .. controls ($($(first)!0.75!(last)$)!{0.1*\wmax+0.4pt}!-90:(last)$)
.. (last);   
\end{tikzpicture}}}
\begin{document}
\[
B=\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\xwidesim[r_4-2r_1]{\substack{r_2-r_1\\ r_3-2r_1}}
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\xwidesim{r}
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A tikz attempt (copied from my [previous answer on zhihu.com](https://www.zhihu.com/question/352249034/answer/870883390), in Chinese):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\def\sim@x@scale{.15}
\def\sim@y@scale{.05}
\def\sim@y@thick{.02}

\newsavebox\sim@upper
\newsavebox\sim@lower

% extensible sim symbol
\NewDocumentCommand{\xSim}{ O{} m }{%
  \TextOrMath{%
    \PackageError{TEST}{`\string\xSim` is valid in math mode only.}{}%
  }{
    % math mode only, hence no need to eliminate spaces
    \sbox\sim@upper{$\scriptsize #2$}
    \sbox\sim@lower{$\scriptsize #1$}
    \pgfmathparse{min(max(\wd\sim@upper/1em, \wd\sim@lower/1em, 1.0), 1.5)}
    \edef\sim@ratio{\pgfmathresult}
    \def\sim@x {\sim@x@scale * \sim@ratio}
    \def\sim@y {\sim@y@scale * \sim@ratio}
    \def\sim@@y{\sim@y@thick * \sim@ratio}
    \pgfmathparse{floor(max(\wd\sim@upper/1em, \wd\sim@lower/1em)) + 1}
    \edef\sim@wd{\pgfmathresult em}
    \mathrel{
      \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-.7ex]
        \filldraw[line width=.2pt] 
          (0, 0)
            .. controls +(\sim@x, \sim@y+\sim@@y) and +(-\sim@x, -\sim@y) .. 
          +(\sim@wd, 0) 
            node[midway, above] {\usebox\sim@upper} 
            node[midway, below] {\usebox\sim@lower}
            .. controls +(-\sim@x, -\sim@y-\sim@@y) and +(\sim@x, \sim@y) .. 
          (0, 0);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {a, aa, aaa, aaaa, aaaaa, aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa} {
  $\frac12 A \xSim{\x} B \sim C \xSim[\x]{} D$ \par
}
\end{document}
```

[image]