# Write text over stretched tilde in math mode

Tags: math-mode

How can write text over stretched tilde in math mode? I want the tilde length to be automatically stretched to the size of the text on it. Like this figure!
[image]
MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[ \sin x\stackrel{x\to 0}{\sim} x \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want the tilde length to be automatically stretched to the size of the text on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a very beautiful notation for my personal taste. Adapting a little bit the code from [How to produce a longer \sim with a small letter on top](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19384/82917)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\makeatletter
% helper macro I snitched somewhere on this site
\newcommand{\smallerstyle}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\scriptstyle\else
  \ifx#1\textstyle\scriptstyle\else
  \scriptscriptstyle\fi\fi
}

\newcommand*{\xsim}[1]{\mathrel{\mathpalette\x@sim{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\x@sim}[2]{%
   \sbox0{\m@th$\smallerstyle#1\,#2\,$}%
   \sbox1{\m@th$#1\sim$}%
   #1\mathop{%
      \ifdim\wd0>\wd1
         \resizebox{\wd0}{\height}{\box1}%
      \else
         \box1
      \fi
   }\limits^{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A \xsim{a} B \xsim{a\to0} C$\par\medskip
$\sin(x) \xsim{x\to0} x$
$\scriptstyle \sin(x) \xsim{x\to0} x$
$\scriptscriptstyle \sin(x) \xsim{x\to0} x$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I do not know who closed the question, but here, unlike that question, the length of the tilde varies.