# Using loop in newcommand to build longer equal sign

Tags: macros, symbols, for-loop

Following [Is there a wider equal sign?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35404/is-there-a-wider-equal-sign) and ["For loop" in newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20341/for-loop-in-newcommand), I have come up with the naive command:

```
\newcount\tmp

\newcommand{\eqlong}[1][2]{% need this to prevent extra vertical space
    =
    \tmp=0
    \loop
        % increment dummy counter
        \advance\tmp by 1
        \joinrel=
        % repeat the loop provided the counter is within specified bound
        \ifnum\tmp<#1
    \repeat
}
```

Supposedly, `\eqlong3` for instance should produce `=\joinrel=\joinrel=`, i.e. an equal sign about 3 times as long as a normal equal sign. The command as I've written doesn't work, but I'm wondering if someone could fix it.

I know a post I linked above (and also [Extendible equals sign](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4813/extendible-equals-sign)) mention the `extarrows` package, but here I just want a symbol whose length I can control with a parameter I pass.

Comment: Your command defines an *optional* argument delimited by square brackets, so the syntax should be `\eqlong[3]` (or `\eqlong` with no argument). See this [tutorial](https://latexref.xyz/_005cnewcommand-_0026-_005crenewcommand.html) on the LaTeX syntax of `\newcommand`.

Comment: As to the actual command, note that `\eqlong[3]` actually defines a symbol that is *four* times as long as `=` (think about where in the code the loop checks whether or not to terminate).

Comment: `% need this to prevent extra vertical space` can not be right. It does save one token of memory (as would `%` after the two `=`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your command defines an optional argument that, if given, must be delimited by square brackets. If I understand your request correctly, you also want `\eqlong[n]` to produce a symbol n-times the length of `=`. As given, it produces a symbol (n+1)-times the length of `=`. This is fixed by simply changing `\tmp=0` to `\tmp=1`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcount\tmp
\newcommand{\eqlong}[1][2]{% need this to prevent extra vertical space
    =
    \tmp=1
    \loop
        % increment dummy counter
        \advance\tmp by 1
        \joinrel=
        % repeat the loop provided the counter is within specified bound
        \ifnum\tmp<#1
    \repeat
}

\begin{document}
$a=b$

$a\eqlong b$ %default, twice as long

$a\eqlong[3] b$ %three times as long
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ahh, I see I messed that up. I thought there was a deeper issue. My bad.

Answer (score 5):

You can make the command as a one-liner:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\eqlong}{O{2}}
 {
  =\prg_replicate:nn { #1 - 1 } { \joinrel= }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$a=b$

$a\eqlong[1] b$% the same as before

$a\eqlong b$% default, twice as long

$a\eqlong[3] b$% three times as long

\end{document}
```

This of course assumes that the argument you pass is a positive integer. If you pass something else, you'll get an error.

[image]

Now let's try and solve a more complicated problem: we want that `\eqlong[3]` produces a relation symbol *exactly* three times long as the equal sign.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\eqlong}{O{2}}{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\eqlong@{#1}}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\eqlong@}{mm}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1=$}%
  \ifnum#2>1
    \makebox[#2\wd\z@][s]{%
      \copy\z@
      \kern-0.5\wd\z@
      \cleaders\hbox{\kern-0.4\wd\z@\copy\z@\kern-0.4\wd\z@}\hfill
      \kern-0.5\wd\z@
      $\m@th#1\mkern-8mu$
      \copy\z@
    }%
  \else
    \copy\z@
  \fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a=b$

$a\eqlong[1] b$% the same as before

$a\eqlong b$% default, twice as long

$a\eqlong[3] b$% three times as long

$a\eqlong[9] b$

\sbox0{${=}{=}{=}{=}{=}$}\the\wd0

\sbox0{$\eqlong[5]$}\the\wd0

$\scriptstyle a=b$

$\scriptstyle a\eqlong[1] b$

$\scriptstyle a\eqlong b$

$\scriptstyle a\eqlong[2]b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, replicating five equals signs has the same width as `\eqlong[5]`.

Answer (score 4):

In OpTeX, you can make the command as a one-liner:

```
\optdef\eqlong [2]{=\fornum 2..\the\opt \do{\joinrel=}}

$a=b$

$a\eqlong[1] b$% the same as before

$a\eqlong b$% default, twice as long

$a\eqlong[3] b$% three times as long

\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcount\tmp

\newcommand{\eqlong}[1][2]{%
    \tmp=0
    \loop
    \ifnum\tmp<\numexpr(#1)\relax
      \ifnum\tmp>0 \joinrel\fi
      \advance\tmp by 1
      =
    \repeat
}

\begin{document}

$a\eqlong[0] b$

$a=b$

$a\eqlong[1] b$

$a\eqlong[2] b$

$a\eqlong b$ %default=2

$a\eqlong[3] b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

---

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\eqlong}[1][2]{%
  \ifnum#1>0 %
    =\ifnum#1>1 \joinrel\fi
    \expandafter\eqlong\expandafter[\the\numexpr(#1)-1\expandafter\relax\expandafter]%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

$a\eqlong[0] b$

$a=b$

$a\eqlong[1] b$

$a\eqlong[2] b$

$a\eqlong b$ %default=2

$a\eqlong[3] b$

\end{document}
```

[image]